# iOS touchmove event - changing backgroundPosition is not smooth

Tags: jquery, ios, parallax, touchmove

I'm trying to create simple parallax effect changing backround position but the movement is not smooth in iOS Safari. Background changes its position only when I release touchscreen, but not when I scroll it.

Javascript:

```
   $(window).bind('touchmove',function(e){  
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#home').css('backgroundPosition', 'center ' + (0-(scrolled*2)) +'px');
    });
```

It actually happens not only with chnaging `backgroundPosition`, but also with `top` for div element:

```
$('#home').css('top', (scrolled*2) +'px');
```

but at the same time `margin-top` works fine and the movement is smooth.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work for iOS in the same way as mousewheel event?

Answer (score 1):

iOS browser will freeze DOM manipulation when scrolling or a gesture happens. This cannot be fixed because it's the problem of the browser. From [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html), it said:

> Note that iOS devices freeze DOM manipulation during scroll, queuing
>   them to apply when the scroll finishes.